# "No export named Button" error for npm package with Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, vite, package.json

I have npm package as reproduced here:
https://stackblitz.com/github/bentaly/components-test/

From: https://github.com/bentaly/components-test

When I add this package to a Vite/React/Typescript project as a dependency such as:

```
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^18.2.0",
   "components-test": "git://github.com/bentaly/components-test"
 },
```

and I use it like so:

```
import { Button } from 'components-test';
...
return <Button>test</Button>
```

I get an error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/components-test.js?v=93ec8a01' does not provide an export named 'Button' (at MyComponent.tsx:6:10)`

*Note: this is not related to adding the dep with a URL, this is a reproduction of an issue in a normally published npm package.*

I am unsure what I am doing wrong, whether it's the entry point of the module or something else. How can I use this shared component?